# How to call a stored procedure of oracle using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I have a stored procedure in oracle for insert in my table employee

Here it is my stored procedure it works fine

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_Emp(idEmp in NUMBER, nameEmp in VARCHAR2, 
addressEmp in VARCHAR2, emailEmp in VARCHAR2,
phoneEmp in CHAR, sexoEmp in CHAR, duiEmp in CHAR, nitEmp in CHAR, salaryEmp in NUMBER, userEmp in VARCHAR2,
contraEmp in VARCHAR2, cargoEmp in VARCHAR2, activoEmp in CHAR)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMPLEADO(IdEmpleado, Nombre, Direccion, Email, Telefono, Sexo, Dui, Nit, Sueldo, Usuario, Contraseña, Cargo, Activo) 
    VALUES (idEmp, nameEmp, addressEmp, emailEmp, phoneEmp, sexoEmp, duiEmp, nitEmp, salaryEmp, userEmp, contraEmp, cargoEmp, activoEmp);
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

But the problem is when I call it in my program from C#, I can't use my sequence EMP_SEQ.nextvalue

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT_EMP", DataBase.Conexion());
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("idEmp", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = EMP_SEQ.nextval;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("nameEmp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtNombre.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("addressEmp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtDireccion.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("emailEmp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtEmail.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("phoneEmp", OracleDbType.Char).Value = txtTelefono.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("sexoEmp", OracleDbType.Char).Value = cb_sexo.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("duiEmp", OracleDbType.Char).Value = txtDUI.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("nitEmp", OracleDbType.Char).Value = txtNIT.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("salaryEmp", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = txtSueldo.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("userEmp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtUser.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("contraEmp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = tb_contraseña.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("cargoEmp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = cb_cargo.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("activoEmp", OracleDbType.Char).Value = obtenerEstado();
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So how can I put my sequence without any problem?

Comment: Why can't you use your sequence? Do you get an error?

Comment: `OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);` is useless since you don't return any data.

Comment: Yeah it says the name EMP_SEQ doesn't exist in the actual context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't `EMP_SEQ.nextvalue` be used *in* the stored procedure, not sent *to* it?  Something like:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLEADO(IdEmpleado, Nombre, Direccion, Email, Telefono, Sexo, Dui, Nit, Sueldo, Usuario, Contraseña, Cargo, Activo) 
VALUES (EMP_SEQ.nextvalue, nameEmp, addressEmp, emailEmp, phoneEmp, sexoEmp, duiEmp, nitEmp, salaryEmp, userEmp, contraEmp, cargoEmp, activoEmp);
```

(Or perhaps placed into a variable on a previous line and then use the variable in the query, whichever you prefer.)

Then your stored procedure wouldn't need to *expect* an identifier, it would be internally generating one.  So the `idEmp` parameter can be removed entirely.

Comment: Thank You! It works,I just put the EMP_SEQ.nextvalue in my stored procedure like yours